# Custom Adapter - Listview setBackground current row

Tags: android, listview, rows

First of all, what I'm trying to achieve is: whenever a person clicks a specific button (this button is on every line of Listview rows), **the row according to that button** should change the color.

This is what I've tried so far without success, because it gives me errors.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);

    ImageButton add_to_cart = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.add_to_cart_butt);
    final ListView lv = (ListView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.product_listview);
    final int thePosition = position;

    add_to_cart.setClickable(true);
    add_to_cart.setId(position);  
    add_to_cart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lv.setFocusable(true); // This is the line where error begins
            lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);         
        }
    });

10-06 15:56:19.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1859): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 15:56:19.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1859): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-06 15:56:19.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at classes.com.example.MyExample.itemAdapter$1.onClick(itemAdapter.java:66)
10-06 15:56:19.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
10-06 15:56:19.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
10-06 15:56:19.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-06 15:56:19.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-06 15:56:19.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-06 15:56:19.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-06 15:56:19.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 15:56:19.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-06 15:56:19.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-06 15:56:19.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-06 15:56:19.302: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the color of rowView. Or edit the tag of the rowView and n
Make a if(rowView.getTag().equals("clicked"){//changeBack}else{//defaultBack}

Comment: My question is: How do I change the color of the specific row?

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it in my application is as follows:

- in your rowResourceId xml file specify an onClick attribute for the button:

  android:onClick="onClickChangeBackground";
- Declare a global final color - defaultColor so you can change the background back to the original if user missed the row he wanted to choose.
- Then inside your main Activity (the one using the list view) develop the method as follows:

  ```
  public void onClickChangeBackground(View v) {
    View rowView = (View) v.getParent()
    ColorDrawable currentColor = (ColorDrawable) rowView.getBackground();
    if(currentColor.getColor() == Color.GREEN)
      rowView.setBackgroundColor(defaultColor);
    else
      rovView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
  }
  ```

Comment: Hello. 
I get this error: `10-07 05:11:44.958: E/AndroidRuntime(1222): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable
10-07 05:11:44.958: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):  at com.example.MyExample.Products.onClickChangeBackground(Products.java:76)`